# Posting to feed with facebook4j is private, how can I make the post public?

Tags: java, facebook

This is the example code I took from another site:

```
PostUpdate post = new PostUpdate(new URL("http://facebook4j.org"))
                .picture(new URL("http://facebook4j.org/images/hero.png"))
                .name("Facebook4J - A Java library for the Facebook Graph API")
                .caption("facebook4j.org")
                .description("Facebook4J is a Java library for the Facebook Graph API.");
fb.postFeed(post);
```

I set the permissions for my application as follows:

```
facebook.setOAuthPermissions("email, publish_actions, publish_stream");
```

I also modified the permissions in my application from my facebook developer acount:

[image: permissions configure]

The problem is that only I can see the post, how can I make it public?

Comment: Is your app still in sandbox mode maybe?

Comment: @CBroe yes, that was it, thank you.. I didn't knew about that

Comment: @CBroe you can add a response with your answer so I can accept it if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app still in sandbox mode maybe?

Everything posted via an app that is still in sandbox mode is only visible to admins/developers/testers of the app.